# Rails Yield With Parameter in Mustache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yield, mustache

I'm using Mustache in Rails 3 with [this gem](https://github.com/goodmike/mustache_rails3) and I'm hitting a roadblock when trying to use Mustache in an instance where I would normally use `yield :parameter`.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= yield :page_title %></title>
  </head>
</html>
```

Show post view:

```
<% content_for :page_title do %>
  <%= SettingsList.site_title + " " + @post.title %>
<% end %>
```

Is there a way to reproduce this behavior with Mustache?  It appears that there may be a way to work this out when the template is compiled:

```
mustache = MustacheClass.new
mustache[:yield_page_title] = content_for(:page_title)
```

But it seems that that would be awkward to work out with my current setup using the mustache_rails3 gem.

I'm also open to any answers that point out a good way to avoid this `yield` approach altogether.  It would be possible to throw enough logic into a `{{page_title}}` tag to handle all my different cases of setting the title, but this seems far from ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the logic for your Mustache templates should be put into the view file. For example, your `show.html.mustache` template should have an associated Ruby view file called `show.rb` where you can put any custom logic for the template.

The template would use a `{{page_title}}` call

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>{{page_title}}</title>
  </head>
</html>
```

And the view file would define a `page_title` method to fill in the template

```
# inside show.rb
def page_title
  SettingsList.site_title + " " + @post.title
end
```